# how to get non-null values for jsonSerialize interface in php?

Tags: php, json

My class implements the

> jsonSerialize in php

Then my class implements the jsonSerialize method and returns get_object_vars($this).

```
 public function JsonSerialize()
{
    $vars = get_object_vars($this);

    return $vars;
}
```

The problem with this is it returns all the values including NULL variables too.
How can I only get the non-null variables as json-output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pass `$vars` to function [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php). If you don't provide it a callback, it will remove everything that is equivalent with [`FALSE`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting)

```
public function JsonSerialize()
{
    $vars = array_filter(get_object_vars($this));

    return $vars;
}
```

If you need to remove only the `NULL` properties and keep other `FALSE`-like values (empty strings, zeroes etc) then you need to write a function that decide what to keep and what to remove:

```
public function JsonSerialize()
{
    $vars = array_filter(
        get_object_vars($this),
        function ($item) {
            // Keep only not-NULL values
            return ! is_null($item);
        }
    );

    return $vars;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just filter the `$vars` vor null values:

```
<?php

public function JsonSerialize()
{
    $vars = get_object_vars($this);

    return array_filter($vars, function ($value) { 
        return null !== $value;
    });
}
```